# Circular crop image while picking it from gallery using ImagePickerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

```
UIImagePickerController* libraryUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

libraryUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

libraryUI.delegate = self;
libraryUI.allowsEditing = YES;
[self presentViewController:libraryUI animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I am using this code to open image picker view and pick an image from gallery. I also set the property "allowsEditing" to "YES" in order to enable the crop image functionality. Now the main issue is that the picker view opened with rectangular crop option. What I want is to get circular crop image option and also want to set the crop circle size (increase or decrease crop circle size).

Comment: it is not available by default use third party library for that

Answer (score 1):

Since it is not available by default, I will suggest you to use this library:
[TOCropViewController](https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController)

It comes with some other features other than circular crop as well. Objective-C and Swift versions are both available